# Styling validation errors to appear inline with inputs not working properly

Tags: jquery, validation, css

I am using client-side validations on a form. Focusing on, then off of the inputs renders the validation errors as `label` tags. The `label` tags are displaying, but are bleeding onto the next line. I've tried altering `display` to `inline-block` and `inline`, tried adjusting `overflow`, etc. But I can't get it to look right. Here is a jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/pp8Uw/

Widening the div that contains the form seems to pull the validation errors onto one line but I dont' want to do that.

**Note:** I'm using bootstrap for some base css, so that provides the container, etc. I altered the out-of-the-box styles a bit for the sake of the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

[**Check this jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/libinvbabu/pp8Uw/1/)

I just changed the `margin` value of `.field_with_errors .message`.

```
.field_with_errors .message { 
    margin:-36px 135px 0;
}
```

Tweak the value to yours to get it in your desired position.

Cheers!!!

Comment: Thanks. That doesn't seem to work for all three errors, unfortunately. Looks like I'd have to do something like that so I was hoping there was something I could do to fix it for all three.